# PaginatedDataTable in flutter

Tags: flutter, paginateddatatable

Who know well PaginatedDataTable class in flutter ? I have discovered it this day and i wonder if it can not resolved my problem. I have data from API REST (PHP/MYSQL) and i want load datas in a table with multiple pages. I prefer don't load all datas in one time because it can be huge and so it can slow the mobile app. So the idea is to load only 10 rows at a time, and so if user want to see more he can click on next for see the next page and so the next datas.

Now, my code is :
As you can see, i user futurebuilder and i send to my api the number of result i want by page (20), my api return so the first 20 results

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'menu_member.dart';
import 'globals.dart' as globals;
import 'appbar_draw.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

// Create a Form widget.
class Affiche_Jetons extends StatefulWidget {
  @override

  _Affiche_Jetons_State createState() {
    return _Affiche_Jetons_State();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.

class _Affiche_Jetons_State extends State<Affiche_Jetons> {
  @override

  Future<List<ligne_jeton>> solde;

  num total;
  num resultbypage=20;
  num nbpages=0;
  num pageactuelle=1;
  num premiereEntree=0;

  Future <List<ligne_jeton>> Liste_Solde_Display(num pageact) async {

    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'https://www.fortune-island.com/app/detail_credits.php';

    premiereEntree=(pageact-1)*resultbypage;

    var data = {
      'id_membre': globals.id_membre,
      'premiere': premiereEntree,
      'resultbypage': resultbypage,
    };

    var data_encode = jsonEncode(data);

    print('appel http');
    print(data_encode);
    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url,body: data_encode,headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json','authorization': globals.token});

    // Getting Server response into variable.

    print(json.decode(response.body));
    var jsondata = json.decode(response.body);
    pageactuelle=pageact+1;
    globals.gems=num.parse(jsondata['gems']);
    globals.credits=num.parse(jsondata['credits']);
    total=num.parse(jsondata['total']);
    nbpages=(total/resultbypage).ceil();

    List<ligne_jeton> lines = [];
    var i=0;
    if (jsondata.containsKey('listec')) {
      for (var u in jsondata['listec']) {
        i = i + 1;
        ligne_jeton line = ligne_jeton(
            u["dates"], u["heure"], u["credits"], u["type"]);
        lines.add(line);
      }
    }
    return lines;
  }

  void initState() {
    solde = Liste_Solde_Display(pageactuelle);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: <Color>[
                  Colors.blue[300],Colors.blue[400]
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Scaffold(
              appBar: drawappbar(true),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              drawer: new DrawerOnly(className: Affiche_Jetons()),
              body:
              Container(
                  height: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .height,
                  width: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width,
                  child:
                  FutureBuilder(
                      future: solde,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                          case ConnectionState.waiting:
                            return new Center(
                              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                          default:
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return new Center(
                                child: new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),);
                            }
                            else {
                              List<ligne_jeton> values = snapshot.data;
                              if (values.isEmpty) {
                                return Container(
                                    child: Center(
                                        child: Text("Aucun mouvement de jetons pour le moment !!!",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                                    )
                                );
                              }
                              else {
                                return ListView(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Center(
                                        child: Container(
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                                            child: Text("DETAIL DE VOS JETONS",textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0,color: Colors.white))
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      DataTable(
                                        columnSpacing: 0,
                                        dataRowHeight: 50,
                                        columns: [
                                          DataColumn(
                                            label: Text("DATE",textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                            numeric: false,
                                            tooltip: "",
                                          ),
                                          DataColumn(
                                            label: Text("JETONS",textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                            numeric: false,
                                            tooltip: "",
                                          ),
                                          DataColumn(
                                            label: Text("TYPE",textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                            numeric: false,
                                            tooltip: "",
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                        rows: List.generate(values.length, (index) {
                                          var parsedDate = DateTime.parse(values[index].date);
                                          final formatter = new DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
                                          var dat = formatter.format(parsedDate);
                                          return DataRow(
                                              cells: [
                                                DataCell(
                                                  Text(dat,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,color:Colors.white)),
                                                ),
                                                DataCell(
                                                    RichText(
                                                      text: TextSpan(
                                                        children: [
                                                          TextSpan(
                                                              text: values[index].nb_jeton.toString()+" ",
                                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,color: Colors.white)
                                                          ),
                                                          WidgetSpan(
                                                              child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.coins,color: Colors.amber[200],size:15)
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                ),
                                                DataCell(
                                                  Text(values[index].type.toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,color: Colors.white)),
                                                ),
                                              ]
                                          );
                                        }).toList(),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                );
                              }
                            }
                        }
                      }
                  )
              )
          )
        ]
    );
  }
}

class ligne_jeton {

  final String date;
  final String heure;
  final String nb_jeton;
  final String type;

  const ligne_jeton (this.date,this.heure,this.nb_jeton, this.type);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement infinite scroll we need a scrollcntroller, currently future builder doesn't supports controller, so try using a listview builder instead of future builder or you can use flutter_pagewise plugin to implement pagination

Comment: with infinite scroll, the user can go down but can go up or no ? Example if i watch the 10 first lines i scroll down i will see the 20 next lines but if want watch again the first lines it will work or not ?

Comment: can you please say me how use flutter pagewise ewactly ?

Answer (score 0):

PaginatedDataTable provides a paginationController which you can pass to the button onPressed function. You can increase page number in the function.

```
onPressed(){
    final PaginatorController _paginatorController = PaginatorController();
    page++;
    _paginatorController.goToNextPage();
    }
```